# undefined method `my_teas_path' for #<#<Class:0xa8930c8>:0xa578cf8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

My current goal in my first rails project is to have a button that will create a `@my_tea` using the attributes of a `@tea` (show page). This is the error I am getting:

> 'undefined method `my_teas_path' for #<#:0xa578cf8>

I have tried having the form in a _new partial inside my_teas/ and inside teas/_add_tea both have given me the same error. Anyway here is my code as it stands.
View:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @my_tea]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @tea.name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :tea_type, :value => @tea.tea_type %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :store, :value => @tea.store %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <%= fields_for [@user, @tea_relationship] do |r| %>
        <%= r.hidden_field :tea_id, :value => @tea.id %>
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Add Tea", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

my_tea controller

```
def new
  @my_tea = MyTea.new
end

def show
  @my_tea = MyTea.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @my_tea = MyTea.new(params[:my_tea])
  if @my_tea.save
    flash[:success] = "Tea added to your teas!"
  else
    redirect_to user_path
  end
end
```

Teas controller:

```
def show
    @tea = Tea.find(params[:id])    
    @my_tea = MyTea.new
    @tea_relationship = TeaRelationship.new
end
```

Routes

```
resources :users do
            resources :my_teas
    end
    resources :teas
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :my_teas, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :tea_relationships, :dependent => :destroy

class MyTea < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

class TeaRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
end
```

Tea model doesn't belong to anything.

Please help rails community your my only hope :p

Update
changing my form to this

```
<%= form_for([@user, @my_tea]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @tea.name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :tea_type, :value => @tea.tea_type %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :store, :value => @tea.store %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <%= fields_for @tea_relationship do |r| %>
        <%= r.hidden_field :tea_id, :value => @tea.id %>
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Add Tea", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

it works and the @my_tea submits but the @tea_relationship doesn't.

Comment: Did you mean to use `@user` instead of `@users` in your `form_for`?

Comment: On what line of the code displayed here does the error occur?

Comment: The first line with the form_for

Comment: You are using `form_for([@user, @my_tea])`, but `@user` is defined nowhere.

Comment: Thanks that helped I put an update with the new form, though now my @tea_relationship doesn't save, I will have to do some more digging unless someone could provide some light on why that isn't working.

Comment: Ok I officially got my app running smoothly. Thanks Mischa for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

So by the look of things and glimpsing through, it seems like you are trying to do some nested forms. It also appears like you have a many-to-many relationship( tea.rb <=> tea_relationship.rb <=> my_tea.rb) Make sure your Models are set up correctly.

[Many to Many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

I am not sure why you are trying to do `[@user, @my_tea]`

[Nested Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Should be more in the lines of

```
<%= form_for @my_tea, :url => posting_path do |f| %>    
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :teas, @my_tea.teas.build do |x| %>
            ...
    <%end%>
    ...
<%end%>
```

hope that helps!

Comment: I updated the post. the tea model doesn't have or belong to another model. MyTeas belongs to user as does TeaRelationship